# update row if it exists else insert it sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns

```
        |Name| Item1 | Item2
         John    A       B
```

Basically i want to be able to update the row if it exists but if it doesnt then insert a new row, i have tried the 'insert or replace into' statement but the problem with that is it will replace the entire row, meaning if i just want to update item1 of john it will create a new row and item2 will disappear

```
  insert or replace into table1(name,item1) values (john, C)
```

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: @Shawn oh ok that was actually easier than i thought it would be, can you post it as an answer so i can accept it?